# JOptionPane how to exit prompt

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestProject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Just about to draw the best piece of artwork in my life, need input please.");

        String name= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Imagine a car, what is it's name?");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ah okay, so it's name is " + name);


        String bodyColour = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cool. What colour was the body of the car? \n Blue, Red, Black, Green or Orange? (More to come in DLC's) ");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mhmm");

        String wheelColour= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Colour of the wheels? ");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Very ordinary...");

    String doorColour = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Last... And probably least, colour of the door?");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finished the drawing!");

    }
}
```

That is my code above, and I was wondering how the user can press the cancel, (because normally it acts like the user pressed 'ok') or the x button in the pop-up prompt, I imagine it could use some type of listener or perhaps System.exit(0); but I am not sure how to implement it as I'm fairly new to Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may solve your problem

```
   if(name == null || (name != null && ("".equals(name))))   
   {
     System.exit(0);// or you can throw exception
    }
```

write this line of code just after your first `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`

Your code (just added the above snippet)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestProject {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Just about to draw the best piece of artwork in my life, need input please.");

    String name= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Imagine a car, what is it's name?");
    if(name == null || (name != null && ("".equals(name))))   
    {
      System.exit(0);// or you can throw exception
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ah okay, so it's name is " + name);


    String bodyColour = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cool. What colour was the body of the car? \n Blue, Red, Black, Green or Orange? (More to come in DLC's) ");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mhmm");

    String wheelColour= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Colour of the wheels? ");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Very ordinary...");

    String doorColour = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Last... And probably least, colour of the door?");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finished the drawing!");

 }
}
```

Comment: Ooh, that's useful! Is there a way I can do a while loop with something like this:

while(blablabla != null) {

//Code

}

Comment: Many logic are there, Actually i not clear in your aim, i gave a solution based on your question. If this answer is useful for you then put a +1 vote

Comment: What I mean is, is there a way that I don't have to type it for each individiual JOptionPane?

Comment: Note: `(name != null && ("".equals(name))` can be reduced to `name.trim().isEmpty()`. So a cleaner condition would be `if (name ==  null || name.trim().isEmpty()) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

If the user presses the cancel or the x button on the prompt, then `showInputDialog` will return null.

Answer (score 0):

Use confirmDialog like this:

```
int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Your Message", "Your Title", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

if(answer == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
    System.out.println("canceled");
} else {
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```